# As a page is redirected how can I use a javascript variable in the innerhtml of the page being loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

```
foo() {
    var fooVar=7;
    location.assign("otherPage.php");
    otherPageobject.html=fooVar;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Imagine the security risk if you directed the user to e.g. a banking website and then injected your own HTML into that page.

Answer (score 0):

The code running on one page can't affect anything on another page, because only one page can be loaded/active at a time.  What you *can* do is send your value to that next page.  For example:

```
location.assign("otherPage.php?fooVar=" + fooVar);
```

Then in that other page you can [get the value from the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/328193) and use it as you see fit.